# Extracting text into columns

Tags: text-mining, orange

I have a set of customer reports, each is in ms word file. they are all in a similar pattern, for example they start with Name: --, Age: --, Date: --, etc...

is there a way to extract particular strings from each file to form a data set.

In orange, I was able to compile the word documents into corpus which I can display as one column (each report is in one cell). Does orange have a way to extract strings into columns (for example if between "age:" and "gender")?

Comment: I don't know Orange but this can be done easily with a bit of programming. You might be able to do it just with a simple 'grep' tool using [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you please suggest a simple tutorial/video that goes through the steps? I am actually an R user not python. The only reason I switched to orange/python now is that I was told it handles text much better.

Comment: there are many ways to use regular expressions with R, but it requires a bit of programming. [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) is a good library.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [Orange3-Text add-on](https://orange.biolab.si/widget-catalog/), [widget Preprocess Text](https://orange.biolab.si/widget-catalog/text-mining/preprocesstext/), Tokenization > Regexp. The [source code](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text/blob/0bb7635ffba7dd178dccbb103e6b33ef1fa0bd34/orangecontrib/text/preprocess/tokenize.py#L82) indicates it's a Python regex, so you might be able to use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern such as:

```regex
(?ix)        # ignore case, ignore comments and whitespace in this RE
(?<=age:\s)  # preceded by 'age: '
.+           # characters you wish to match
(?=gender:)  # followed by 'gender:'
```

Comment: thank you. this a great idea. orange is a GUI for python and actually there is a widget to add and run a python code, so I think I will try your method. there are plenty of online tutorials on text mining that I found, is there a particular one you recommend for beginners?

Comment: For beginners, _all_ of them.